# Does a simple delete query go in any particular order?

Tags: sql-server

Given the query:

```
DELETE FROM mytable;
```

and assuming mytable has as single autoincrementing integer PK

Does the deletion go in any particular order, or is it random? My assumption is that under the hood it goes from oldest (lowest) PK to newest (higher), but not really sure.

Is this ordering (if any) universal among the big database engines?

Comment: If you issue a delete against a table with no where clause it deletes pages, not rows. And even if you delete certain rows there is no guarantee of the order. And why would it matter anyway? The delete statement is a single atomic unit of work. It either succeeds or fails as a batch. This is the point of the ATOMIC portion of ACID. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: SQL Server operations are set-based.  As far as the user is concerned, the query you posted will make all the records in `mytable` vanish simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

"truncate table" is a bulk operation, hence performs better than "delete from".
A PK does not guarantee a specific order.

Comment: To actually matter you would either need to row level triggers, or set row count n, where n is less than the record count in the table. SQL server is free too choose in which order the deletion will happen. However, it might start on one end of the table. For a clustered index, you will effectively start deleting either from beginning  or from the end and remove either the biggest or the smallest keys.